# How to fetch json object using Retrofit library

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

This is my json data

```
{
      "RiderProfile": {
        "ID": 2,
        "Name": "aka",
        "Email": "ak@ak.com"
      }
    }
```

This is how I put parameters

```
@GET("/api/rider/GetLogin?Email=ak@ak.com&Password=123 ")
    public Call GetLogin(
            @Path("Email") String Email,
            @Path("Password") String Password);
```

Fetching json data using Retrofit library

```
     @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
            String respoStr = response.body().toString();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            DataHandler.webData = gson.fromJson(respoStr,WebData.class);
            String name = DataHandler.webData.Rider.getEmail();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome"+name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: and what's your question? Is there some problem with your code you would like help with? It's not clear what your issue is.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for response, I am fetching json object but can't get respone please look into my code and tell me is this code is okay or something wrong.

Comment: "can't" means what exactly? What debugging have you done? Give us a description of the problem including any HTTP statuses, error messages, unexpected data values, unexpected code behaviour etc. And then tell us exactly what you expected to happen instead.

Answer (score 0):

As the question seems unclear to me, I guess you need to have JSON response in a java object.
For that, create a model (POJO class) for your JSON response. The following link will be helpful for it : http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Then use the model class as generics for **Call** class

For eg.

```
@GET("/api/rider/GetLogin?Email=ak@ak.com&Password=123 ")
    public Call<YOUR_MODEL> GetLogin(
            @Path("Email") String Email,
            @Path("Password") String Password);
```

And you can cast the **Response** object in the `onResponse()` method into your POJO class. By doing this, you can get JSON values by accessing getters and setters of your POJO class.

Comment: thank you sumeet for answered, My question is how to cast the JSON object in the onResponse() method,

Comment: I can cast this JSON data easily
{
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "Name": "aka",
    "Email": "ak@ak.com",
    "Mobile": "1212121212",
  }
}
but I am getting problem to cast this JSON data
{
      "RiderProfile": {
        "ID": 2,
        "Name": "aka",
        "Email": "ak@ak.com"
      }
    }

Comment: I hope the issue has been fixed. If it's not:
Referring to your previous comment, structures of both the responses are different. Make sure that the JSON that you want to use is casted into respected POJO class. 
I mean POJO classes for both the structures will be different, use appropriate one while casting.